# Rails to load app reviews from iTunes store

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I build a simple website that is a portfolio for iphone apps, the site is built in ruby on rails 4, I need to have certain apps reviews and ratings being loaded from itunes store, as in I have a URL that connetcs to an iphone app page in itunes store, I want to make sure my website always displays the latest ratings on that app. 
I don't know how do accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you look into https://github.com/dewski/itunes

**Example Response**

```
{
  "artist_id" : 954266,
  "artist_name" : "Green Day",
  "artist_view_url" : "http://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/green-day/id954266?uo=4",
  "artwork_url100" : "http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/049/Features/1e/17/05/dj.rpihtiig.100x100-75.jpg",
  "artwork_url30" : "http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/049/Features/1e/17/05/dj.rpihtiig.30x30-50.jpg",
  "artwork_url60" : "http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/049/Features/1e/17/05/dj.rpihtiig.60x60-50.jpg",
  "collection_censored_name" : "Dookie",
  "collection_explicitness" : "explicit",
  "collection_id" : 5132583,
  "collection_name" : "Dookie",
  "collection_price" : 9.99,
  "collection_view_url" : "http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/she/id5132583?i=5132563&uo=4",
  "content_advisory_rating" : null,
  "country" : "USA",
  "currency" : "USD",
  "disc_count" : 1,
  "disc_number" : 1,
  "kind" : "song",
  "preview_url" : "http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/027/Music/0e/86/7a/mzm.wchstext.aac.p.m4a",
  "primary_genre_name" : "Alternative",
  "release_date" : "2003-04-22 07:00:00 Etc/GMT",
  "track_censored_name" : "She",
  "track_count" : 15,
  "track_explicitness" : "notExplicit",
  "track_id" : 5132563,
  "track_name" : "She",
  "track_number" : 8,
  "track_price" : 1.29,
  "track_time_millis" : 134293,
  "track_view_url" : "http://itunes.apple.com/us/album/she/id5132583?i=5132563&uo=4",
  "wrapper_type" : "track"
}
```